# PHP if(isset) not working properly with 2 radio groups and 1 textname

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Again the issue I am having is that instead of throwing the 'error' message when the text field or either of the two radio groups is NOT selected, it throws them ONLY when all 3 fields have been filled in. Here is the entire html & PHP page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="hw1.php">
<h1>
<label for="name2"></label>
Music Survey
</h1>
<p>Please Enter Your First Name
<label for="firstname"></label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" 
size="18"maxlength="18"  />
</p>
<h3>Please Enter Your Age Group</h3>
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="Youth" id="agegroup_0" />
Youth</label>(12 - 21)<br /><label>
<input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="Adult" id="agegroup_1" />
Adult</label>(22 - 50)<br /> <label>
<input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="Elderly" id="agegroup_2"/>
Elderly</label>(51 - Dead)
</p>
<h3>Please Enter Your Favorite Style Of Music</h3>
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Pop"  id="musicpreference_0" />
Pop</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Country"    
id="musicpreference_1" />
Country</label>
<br />
<label>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Rock" id="musicpreference_2" />
Rock</label>
</h3>
</h3>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit Your Anwser" />
</p>
<p><br />
<input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset My Anwsers" 
/>
<br />
</p>
</form>
</body>

And here is the PHP portion:
<body>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['agegroup'])
    || isset($_POST['music']) 
    || !empty($_POST['firstname']))

    {
    echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
    }
    else
    {

 ?>
<h1>Thank For Taking the Survey <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?> </h1>

<?php

    if ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Youth' && $_POST['music'] == 'Pop')
    {
        echo 'Pop Music Is Appropriate For Young People';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Youth' && $_POST['music'] == 'Rock')
    {
        echo 'Adults Listen To Rock Music, Not Young People';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Youth' && $_POST['music'] == 'Country')
    {
        echo "Country Music Is For Your Grandparents";
    }


    if ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Adult' && $_POST['music'] == 'Pop')
    {
        echo 'Adults Don\'t Listen To Pop Music, Their Kids Do ';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Adult' && $_POST['music'] == 'Rock')
    {
        echo 'Rock Music Is Just Right For Adults';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Adult' && $_POST['music'] == 'Country')
    {
        echo 'Country Music Is What The Elderly Listen To!';
    }


    if ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Elderly' && $_POST['music'] == 'Pop')
    {
        echo 'Pop Music Is For Young Kids';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Elderly' && $_POST['music'] == 'Rock')
    {
        echo 'Adults Listen To Rock Music';
    }
    elseif ($_POST['agegroup'] == 'Elderly' && $_POST['music'] == 'Country')
    {
        echo 'Country Music Is Perfect For The Elderly';
    }
}
?>

</body>
```

I have an if statement that I need to return as both radio groups have been selected and the text box has been filled in or else, deliver and error message and for some reason it's not working, could someone help me figure out what I am missing? The 'agegroup' and 'music' are the radio groups and the 'firstname' is the text box.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['agegroup']) && isset($_POST['music'])
&&!($_POST['firstname'] == NULL))
{
?>
<h1>Thank For Taking the Survey <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?> </h1>
else
{
echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: `&&!($_POST['firstname'] == NULL))` try removing the `!`. Or `&& ($_POST['firstname'] != NULL))` hard to say which condition you're looking to get.

Comment: I will try that right now.

Comment: The error reporting did not do anything, I need the php to display an error if any of the three pieces are not present, therefore if the 'firstname' is left blank or either one of the 'agegroup' or 'music' radio groups is left blank, then the "echo" will appear

Comment: I tried switching around the '!' and that did not work either

Comment: Try this then `if(isset($_POST['agegroup']) && isset($_POST['music']) && !empty($_POST['firstname']))` - if that doesn't work, then I don't know what else will. You'll need to post your HTML form.

Comment: NULL != blank field. you either need to use `empty()` as suggested, or check `... != ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a named submit button, you can use the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) 
   && isset($_POST['agegroup']) 
   && isset($_POST['music']) 
   && !empty($_POST['firstname']))
```

which will also check if the submit button was clicked.

Or you can use:

```
if(isset($_POST['agegroup']) 
   && isset($_POST['music']) 
   && !empty($_POST['firstname']))
```

Both of which worked while testing the following, and as an example which you can modify to include the variables you are using for the rest of your form:

```
<form method="post" action="">

Age group: <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="agegroup1">
<input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="agegroup2">

<br>
Music: <input type="radio" name="music" value="music1">
<input type="radio" name="music" value="music2">
<br>
First name <input name="firstname" type="text">
<br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php

// if(isset($_POST['agegroup']) && isset($_POST['music']) && !empty($_POST['firstname']))

$name = $_POST['firstname'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']) 
   && isset($_POST['agegroup']) 
   && isset($_POST['music']) 
   && !empty($_POST['firstname']))

    {
    echo "<h1>Thank For Taking the Survey " .$name. "</h1>";
    }

else
    {
    echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
    }
```

---

**Edit:** (this code block)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['agegroup'])
    || isset($_POST['music']) 
    || !empty($_POST['firstname']))

    {
    echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
    }
```

What this is saying is if they're set and not empty, then fill out the form.

This needs to be the reverse: *(if NOT set OR empty...)*

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['agegroup'])
    || !isset($_POST['music']) 
    || empty($_POST['firstname']))

    {
    echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
    }
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, thank you very much for the help, I will post result after I try it.

Comment: Fred, This is getting me closer, I have many more 'if' statements below in this code that I am wondering if they might be throwing something off, b/c it still only throws the error when all 3 areas (2 Radio groups and 1 text box) are filled in, instead of throwing the error ONLY if any of the 3 areas are not filled in and/or selected.

Comment: @Mike Try changing the `&&` to `||` - meaning `OR` this, `OR` that etc. rather than `AND` this, `AND` that

Comment: Same result, I am going to post my entire html and PHP. I have the feeling something further down in the program is messing it up, b/c simply just from a logical stand point, these fixes make sense.

Comment: @Mike Reload my answer and look near the end under **Edit:** (this code block)

Comment: Fred, you are worth your weight in GOLD! That was it! Thank you so much for your patience and help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Mike I'm glad to have been of help Mike and you're quite welcome. *"Thank you so much for your patience"* - I grow "cactus", I have to be lol *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enclose the first two conditions on a single () then continue with 3rd separately. Like this. If((cond1 && cond2) && (cond3))

Comment: Tried, nothing changed, it keeps throwing the 'echo' when all three pieces of data are filled in, exact opposite of what I need

Comment: Try this &&($_POST['firstname'] != null)

Comment: I just did that too, same results: all three fields filled = echo